# Rstudio with just console

Tags: installation, rstudio

I installed R and Rstudio but just shows the console and doesn't  give me the option to open it on the side or top.
At the top of the page says RGui !! I used R and rstudio before and I am trying to download them on my new laptop.

just see console on Rstudio on my windows laptop

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the Menu above the console, you can locate `Tools > Global Options... > Pane Layout`. You can customize the layout, like so:

[image: Sample Pane Layout]

If the Menu is not visible, try the following keyboard shortcuts: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, then <kbd>G</kbd>, to open the Global Options window.

Edit: I just saw that you mentioned RGui. RGui is the native development environment for R. Please search for RStudio in your Start Menu.